# Problem with editing representation

Tags: arcobjects

How we can edit the representation of a layer programmatically in DotNet ?

''Representations allow you to customize the appearance of features by storing symbol information with the feature geometry inside feature classes. This additional control can help you meet stringent cartographic specifications or simply improve the display.''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by looking at [IRepresentationClass](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRepresentationClass_Interface/0025000007r7000000/).

From IRepresentationClass you can access the representations of individual features and modify them by overriding items or creating a free representation with graphics.  See [IRepresentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IRepresentation_Interface/0025000007r6000000/) for this information.